# Handle multiple $watch in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have three models startDate,endDate,durationMillis in scope. If any of the value is changed by use, I need to calculate the other model by $watch.

```
$scope.$watch('startDate', function()
{
    $scope.endDate = new Date($scope.startDate.getTime() + $scope.durationMillis);
});

$scope.$watch('endDate', function()
{
    $scope.durationMillis = $scope.endDate.getTime() + $scope.startDate.getTime();
});

$scope.$watch('durationMillis', function()
{
    $scope.startDate = new Date($scope.endDate.getTime() - $scope.durationMillis.getTime());
});
```

Here, my problem is when user changes start date/end date/duration, $watch of calculated attributes(not changed by user) has been called recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I have found for this kind of problems is using an external flag and the following ugly code:

```
var triggeredBySystem = false;

$scope.$watch('startDate', function() {
    if( !triggeredBySystem ) {
        $scope.endDate = new Date($scope.startDate.getTime() + $scope.durationMillis);
        triggeredBySystem = true;
    }
    else {
        triggeredBySystem = false;
    }
});

$scope.$watch('endDate', function() {
    if( !triggeredBySystem ) {
        $scope.durationMillis = $scope.endDate.getTime() + $scope.startDate.getTime();
        triggeredBySystem = true;
    }
    else {
        triggeredBySystem = false;
    }
});

$scope.$watch('durationMillis', function() {
    if( !triggeredBySystem ) {
        $scope.startDate = new Date($scope.endDate.getTime() - $scope.durationMillis.getTime());
        triggeredBySystem = true;
    }
    else {
        triggeredBySystem = false;
    }
});
```

I would be interested in better solutions myself...

(I would refactor the common code above of course, but here I am just demonstrating the principle.)

Comment: Thanks. As of now worked great. But looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I guess a Solution for the loop could be to unwatch other watches and then re init the watches (still feel dirty) :

blog for unbind : http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2480-unbinding-watch-listeners-in-angularjs.htm

```
function init(){
    $scope.unbindStart = $scope.$watch('startDate', function()
    {
        $scope.unbindStart();
        $scope.unbindEnd();
        $scope.unbindDuration();
        $scope.endDate = new Date($scope.startDate.getTime() + $scope.durationMillis);

        $timeout(setupWatch,10);
    });

    $scope.unbindEnd = $scope.$watch('endDate', function()
    {
        $scope.unbindStart();
        $scope.unbindEnd();
        $scope.unbindDuration();
        $scope.durationMillis = $scope.endDate.getTime() + $scope.startDate.getTime();

        $timeout(setupWatch,10);
    });

    $scope.unbindDuration = $scope.$watch('durationMillis', function()
    {
        $scope.unbindStart();
        $scope.unbindEnd();
        $scope.unbindDuration();
        $scope.startDate = new Date($scope.endDate.getTime() - $scope.durationMillis.getTime());

        $timeout(setupWatch,10);
    });
}

function setupWatch(){

    init();

}
```